# Pragmatics of Pagination with Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, pagination

This is more of a pragmatical question in regards to implementing pagination with the usage of Cassandra. I have read the documentation in regards to the Page state and that it should not be exposed to end user as it is not encrypted and creates the possibility of unwanted tampering.

So, with all that said, my question is what are the pragmatics and best practices in terms of using the PageState object when implementing an API that needs to fetch the next records in line upon scrolling?

Comment: My apologies but I don't quite understand your question. Are you able to ask it differently and perhaps provide some background information? Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

After re-reading your question, I think I understand now what you're trying to achieve.

You are correct in saying that you shouldn't expose the page state to end-users of your application. I don't think there will be anything catastrophic if the page state is modified/tampered by a user but if they do, it will either return unpredictable results or be unusable and the driver will throw an exception.

On your question of what is best practice when implementing an API to retrieve the next "page" of results, I would recommend separating the implementation of your API from the logic which requests the records from the DB.

For example, don't use the driver's page state in your API but instead implement an option `page=next` so the HTTP endpoint looks like `/api/users?page=next`. Cheers!